# NodeJs routes not working from inner page

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to develop an application in NodeJs using express framework. My routing is working when I navigating from home to inner pages. But If I want to navigate from some inner page to homepage then it is not working.

Below is my app.js code.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const engines = require('consolidate');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//declare all routers
var home = require(path.join(__dirname, "/routes/index"));
var myaccount = require(path.join(__dirname, "/routes/myaccount"));

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.engine('html', engines.handlebars);
var defaultViewPath = path.join(__dirname, "/views");
app.set('views', defaultViewPath);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use('/', home);
app.use('/myaccount', myaccount);
```

Here if I have navigated from home to myaccount - Its working
But if I am navigating from myaacount to home - It reloads the same page.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define routing using methods of the **Express** app object, use `app.get()` to handle GET requests

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// When GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});

// When GET request is made to the myaccount
app.get('/myaccount', function (req, res) {
  res.render('myaccount');
});

app.get('/myaccount/innerpage', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Inner Page');
});

//Page Not Found
app.use(function(req, res){
    //render the html page
    //res.render('404');
    res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Hope this could help you

Comment: When I am in myaccount page, its working fine. But if I am in "myaccount/innerpage" and then I want to come to myaccount page. It send me to "myaccount/myaccount". Please Help.

Comment: You should define your routes properly, I modified the answer and I tested, no problem!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was giving wrong URLs in navigation. I have forgotten to append "/"before each page URL. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `app.get` and `app.post` Route Methods

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){ 
 res.render('home');
});

app.get('/myaccount',function(req,res){      
  res.render('myaccount');
});
```

Or Create Router File For Home & myAccount

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Home Page')
})

module.exports = router
```

in Your `app.js` or `index.js` file , require route.js

```
var home = require('./route');
app.use('/', home)
```